How do I generate rows of predefined values from a SELECT statement?
In SQLite I want to return a list that I type in myself (for further left join SQL commands):
ABC
DEF
GHI

Not existing in any table but manually entered strings (like how SELECT 'ABC' returns ABC, but with multiple rows at once). I could use SELECT 'ABC' UNION SELECT 'DEF' UNION SELECT 'GHI' but that seems inefficient.

Or SELECT value FROM json_each('["ABC", "DEF", "GHI"]')
